# Looking for a subgroup $H$ of $D_{2019}$ with the following properties:

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

I m looking for a subgroup $H$ of the dihedral group $(D_{2019},\circ)$ so that:

With $(D_{2019},\circ)$ the group containing as elements 
$b$: a reflexion on a symmetry axis, and
 $a$: a rotation of $\frac{2\pi}{2019}$
On a “2019-gon”

- $H \neq D_{2019}$
- $H$ has an element with order $673$
- $a^{102} \circ b \in H \circ a$

What I have tried so far: out of the 3rd requirement I gathered: $a^{102}\circ b = a^{103}\circ b \circ a \in H \circ a$

So I thought that $H=\{1,a^3,a^6,…,ab,a^3b,…a^{2018}b\}$

But since $a^{103} \notin H$ This cannot be it. Where did I go wrong?

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Do you mean, "dihedral group"?

Comment: Given the number $2019$,  I'm guessing this is from an old exam or competition. Am I right? Please share the details of the question's origin.

Comment: What is $a$? What is $b$?  The dihedral group has a very easy structure, and since $2019 = 3\times 673$, this seems rather straightforward...

Comment: @Shaun, thank you for the recommendation above I ll try to implement this. I m preparing an exam with old exam question we received. The groep in question consists of rotations (a-2019 indicates that one rotation is by 2π/2019, so a^2019 is 360° turn) and mirroring (b) in the flat. 
To be candid. In the lecture it has been introduced to us that way, and I m not sure how it is called in English.

Answer (score 3):

There's *anti-commutativity* in dihedral groups.   Here $ab=ba^{-1}.$

So $$a^{102}ba^{-1}=a^{103}b.$$

So, take $H=\langle a^3,a^{103}b\rangle.$

Then $H=G$, because $a^{103}b\in G\setminus \langle a^3\rangle $.

Thus there's no way to.

Comment: So is due to the anti-commutativity: $a^{102}\circ b = b\circ a^{-1917}$? How can then $a^{102}\circ b \in H\circ a$ A secondary class of $H$

Comment: Only if $H=G$....

Comment: Thank you. I also thought that this wouldn’t work.

Comment: How about$ H= \{1,a^{103},a^{206},…,a^{103}\circ b,a^{203}\circ b\}$ because then $a^{102}\circ b \in H\circ a $ and as well $ord(a^{309})=673$,

But this wouldn’t be a group anymore,

Comment: Since $H\neq (D_{2019},\circ)$

Comment: Right.   The element of order $673$ insures the index is at most $3$.  One more element and it's at most $2$.  But that can't be because $a^{103}b$ has order $2$.  So $H=G$.